# JSON fields in Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, json-extract

I am wanting to split out 'housing' key onto different rows. So in this example I would expect 4 rows. Within each row would have the following columns:

id (this is the key on the table), housing.id, housing.name, user.id, hours, isplanningtime

Example of JSON.

`[{"housing":{"id":"02d3ca45-36b3-4114-91b7-39ed12e1548b","name":"texting"},"user":{"id":"75bd4cad-acc9-420d-9d5e-4d2851a4b9c4","name":"person_person","jobTitle":"Sales Manager","avatar":null,"email":"sales@123.co.uk","disabled":false},"hours":4,"isPlanningTime":false},{"housing":{"id":"02d3ca45-36b3-4114-91b7-39ed12e1548b","name":"testing"},"user":null,"hours":4,"isPlanningTime":false},{"housing":{"id":"02d3ca45-36b3-4114-91b7-39ed12e1548b","name":"testing"},"user":null,"hours":4,"isPlanningTime":false},{"housing":{"id":"02d3ca45-36b3-4114-91b7-39ed12e1548b","name":"testing"},"user":null,"hours":4,"isPlanningTime":false}]`

I have managed to do this with the following code

```
    SELECT cd.id,
           json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 0), 'housing', 'id') AS housing_id_0,
           json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 0), 'housing', 'name') AS housing_name_0,
           json_extract_path_text(Json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 0), 'user', 'id') AS user_id_0,
           json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 0), 'hours') AS hours_0,
           json_extract_path_text(json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 0), 'isPlanningTime') AS isPlanningTime_0
    FROM "data" cd
    LEFT JOIN "field" c ON c.id = cd.field_id
    WHERE c.name = 'time'
```

Using Union All, I copied the code and changed

```
    json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 1)
    json_extract_array_element_text(cd.value, 2)
```

and so on.

The problem is there could be 100+ instances of 'housing' in the JSON.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnesting a super array and the AWS docs describe how to do this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

This will basically make a new row for each element in the top array of your data.  Then you can apply your selection SQL of the individual fields that you want to extract.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to get a new row for each element but I can't seem to extract to individual fields. 

I have tried both the following but the first is an error message _ERROR: function json_extract_path_text(super, "unknown", "unknown") does not exist_. 

The 2nd is returning null for all the rows.

`json_extract_path_text(o, 'housing', 'id') AS housing_id`

 `json_extract_path_text(o::varchar, 'housing', 'name') AS housing_name`

I have `JSON_TYPEOF(o)` and it is returning object. Could this be the issue?

Comment: To perform the unnesting you needed your json text to be stored as a super data type.  It is not clear from your original question if this is how it was natively stored or not but if you got the unnesting to work it's a super now.  So you should be able to use simple super navigaion to address the different fields in the super.  Try just selecting o.housing.id from the unnested super.  If this doesn't work update the question with the query you have so far and I can take a closer look.

Comment: One other thing to add - since one of you json identifiers has capital letters you will need to enable  case sensitive identifiers in your Redshift session - SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;

Comment: Thank you so much, Bill. I enclosed the identifiers with double quotes and it is pulling the expected data.
Thank you again for your help and patience.